# Dynamic Join condition Depending on Ranking

Tags: sql-server

I have 3 tables

```
CREATE TABLE TableA(SomeID INT NOT NULL, Ranking smallint not null)

INSERT INTO TableA(1,1)
INSERT INTO TableA(2,2)
INSERT INTO TableA(3,1)
INSERT INTO TableA(4,1)
INSERT INTO TableA(5,2)
```

I have 2 detailed tables and want to join to determine Join condition from TableA depending on Ranking column

```
CREATE TABLE TableB(SomeID INT NOT NULL, Somedetailedinfo varchar(10))
INSERT INTO TableB(1,'2019-10-21')
INSERT INTO TableB(2,'2018-10-21')
INSERT INTO TableB(3,'2017-10-21')
INSERT INTO TableB(4,'2016-10-21')
INSERT INTO TableB(5,'2015-10-21')

CREATE TABLE TableC(SomeID INT NOT NULL, Somedetailedinfo varchar(10))
INSERT INTO TableC(1,'2016-10-21')
INSERT INTO TableC(2,'2015-10-21')
INSERT INTO TableC(3,'2014-10-21')
INSERT INTO TableC(4,'2013-10-21')
INSERT INTO TableC(5,'2012-10-21')
```

I want to Join TableA with TableB or TableC depending on value of Ranking.
If Ranking=1 Join TableA with TableB 
If Ranking=2 Join TableA with TableC

Expected OUTPUT is

```
SomeID,Somedetailedinfo
1,'2019-10-21'
2,'2015-10-21'
3,'2017-10-21'
4,'2016-10-21'
5,'2012-10-21'
```

How do I do this?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: `LEFT JOIN` to both tables. In the `ON` include with the `SomeID` the appropriate `Ranking` value. In the `Where` clause, filter out the `NULL` values from tables `B` and `C`.

Comment: That sample data, is the second set meant to have `TableB` twice?

Answer (score 0):

*Assuming that your Sample data should look like this:*

```
CREATE TABLE TableA(SomeID INT NOT NULL, Ranking smallint not null)

INSERT INTO TableA VALUES (1,1)
INSERT INTO TableA VALUES (2,2)
INSERT INTO TableA VALUES (3,1)
INSERT INTO TableA VALUES (4,1)
INSERT INTO TableA VALUES (5,2)
GO

CREATE TABLE TableB(SomeID INT NOT NULL, Somedetailedinfo varchar(10))
INSERT INTO TableB VALUES (1,'2019-10-21')
INSERT INTO TableB VALUES (2,'2018-10-21')
INSERT INTO TableB VALUES (3,'2017-10-21')
INSERT INTO TableB VALUES (4,'2016-10-21')
INSERT INTO TableB VALUES (5,'2015-10-21')

CREATE TABLE TableC(SomeID INT NOT NULL, Somedetailedinfo varchar(10))
INSERT INTO TableC VALUES (1,'2016-10-21')
INSERT INTO TableC VALUES (2,'2015-10-21')
INSERT INTO TableC VALUES (3,'2014-10-21') 
INSERT INTO TableC VALUES (4,'2013-10-21')
INSERT INTO TableC VALUES (5,'2012-10-21')
```

The requirement implies that you have a denormalisation problem, however, you can do this with 2 `LEFT JOIN`s:

```
SELECT A.SomeID,
       ISNULL(B.Somedetailedinfo,C.Somedetailedinfo) AS Somedetailedinfo
FROM TableA A
     LEFT JOIN TableB B ON A.SomeID = B.SomeID
                       AND A.Ranking = 1
     LEFT JOIN TableC C ON A.SomeID = C.SomeID
                       AND A.Ranking = 2;
```